# How to utilize Docker to run tests for multiple languages on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, docker, go, travis-ci

I am attempting to create a CI/CD pipeline with Travis CI that tests the front-end, tests the back-end, and deploys. The front-end is using Node, the back-end is using Go.

My repository is structured as follows:

```
- client
    - DockerFile
    - ...(front-end code)
- server
    - DockerFile
    - ...(back-end code)
- .travis.yml
```

Would I be able to utilize the DockerFiles in some fashion to execute tests for both sides of the application and have Travis report their results properly?

I'm not well versed with either tools so I was hoping to get some input before I dig myself into a hole. I plan on using a combination of Travis stages and docker build/docker run commands. Something like this:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test client side
      before_script:
        - cd client
        - docker build ...
      script:
        docker run image /bin/sh -c "run node tests"
      after_script:
        - cd ..

    - stage: test server side
      before_script:
        - cd server
      script:
        docker run image /bin/sh -c "run go tests"
      after_script:
        - cd ..

    - stage: deploy
      script: skip
      deploy:
        - provider: s3
            skip_cleanup: true
            on:
            branch: master
```

[This doc page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/share-docker-image/) makes it looks promising, but the inclusion of `language: ruby` and `script: - bundle exec rake test` throws me off. I am not sure why Ruby is required if the tests are ran through docker (at least that's what it looks like).

## Update 1

I believe I got it to work correctly with the client side of the application.

Here is what I got:

```
services:
  - docker

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      before_script:
        - docker pull node:12
      script:
        - docker run --rm -e CI=true -v $(pwd)/client:/src node:12 /bin/sh -c "cd src; npm install; npm test"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Did you try your setup without Ruby?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thank you! After a good amount of tweaking, I think I got it to work the client side of the app. It seems to be reporting the results correctly. I still have to look into exactly how the docker run exit codes work with travis. I updated my post with my changes